# Is a symmetric monoidal category ("tensor-category" in P. Deligne & J.S. Milne's vocabulary) neccessarily locally small?

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

Let $(\mathcal{C},\otimes,\mathbf{1},\phi,\psi)$ (I will denote this by just $(\mathcal{C},\otimes)$) be a tensor-category (in P. Deligne & J.S. Milne's vocabulary, see https://www.jmilne.org/math/xnotes/tc2018.pdf), or we could call it a symmetric monoidal category.

Furthermore, assume that $(\mathcal{C},\otimes)$ is **closed**, by which we mean that for every object $B$ in $(\mathcal{C},\otimes)$ we have that $- \otimes B \dashv \underline{\text{Hom}}(B,-)$, i.e. that $\underline{\text{Hom}}(B,-)$ is right-adjoint to the functor $- \otimes B$.

Is it the case that $(\mathcal{C},\otimes)$ is neccessarily locally small?

The reason for asking, is the proof of proposition $3.2$ here: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+hom#ClosedMonoidalCategory

It seems like they use yoneda:s embedding in the proof, which assumes that $(\mathcal{C},\otimes)$ is locally small, but the proof only assumes closed symmetric monoidal.

Comment: Typically, I would assume all categories are locally small unless explicitly stated otherwise (and it doesn't seem there is such a statement in the linked document).

Comment: Local smallness is only used to ensure the class of natural transformations from a not necessarily representable functor and therefore to define the category that is the target of the Yoneda embedding. However, the Yoneda lemma allows the definition of the classes of natural transformations from representables. Thus the corestriction of the Yoneda embedding's codomain to the category of representable functors is well-defined. This is what's actually used in the proof in proposition 3.2, not the full Yoneda embedding.

Answer (score 0):

No. Any presheaf category on a category with finite products has finite products and is therefore symmetric monoidal. But if the original category is locally small, then the presheaf category is locally small if and only if the original category is (essentially) small.